# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.csvreader.CsvReader

Tags: java

I'm developing an application for sending bulk emails from multiple senders in a continuous loop. Sender email-ID's are stored in a csv file and I am reading that in ReadFile class and calling it in servlet class where I am also calling an email utility class which have email sending functions.

ReadFile.java

```
CsvReader senders; 
public List<String> read(){
  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
    senders = new CsvReader("C:/Users/dc/Documents/Senderlist.csv");
    senders.readHeaders();

    while (senders.readRecord()) {
      String SenderID = senders.get("SenderID");
      // perform program logic here
      System.out.println("Sender ID is: "+SenderID );
      al.add(SenderID);
    }
    senders.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return al;
}
```

Servlet.java:

```
public class MailController extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String ExchangeIP;
  private String port;
  ReadFile rf;
  /**
   * @throws IOException 
   * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
   */
  public MailController() throws IOException {
    rf=new ReadFile();
  }

  public void init() {
    // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    ExchangeIP = context.getInitParameter("ExchangeIP");
    port = context.getInitParameter("port");
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // read from field
    List<File> uploadedFiles= saveUploadedFiles(request);
    String sender=request.getParameter("sender");// reading from the form page
    String recipient=request.getParameter("recipient");
    String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
    String content=request.getParameter("content");
    String resultMessage = ""; //null
    try {
      List sendersInput = rf.read();
      // print all the elements in the list 
      Iterator itr = sendersInput.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
        EmailUtility.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port, itr.next(), recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);           
        resultMessage = "The e-mail has been sent successfully";
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
    } finally {
      request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
      getServletContext()
        .getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp")
        .forward(request, response);
    }   
  }
}
```

While running this I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.csvreader.CsvReader
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at com.project.util.ReadFile.read(ReadFile.java:20)
    at com.project.controller.MailController.doPost(MailController.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

How to resolve this error.

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: using apache tomcat server

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `opencsv.jar` library. 
Specify it in your `java` command with

```
java -cp opencsv.jar:...
```

Comment: It looks like the OP is running this as a web application. In that case, he should put `opencsv.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of his war file.

Comment: I have added opencsv.jar in WEB-INF/lib ..still im gettting same error.

Comment: Which web/app-server do you use?

Comment: apache tomcat server

Comment: There is also the option: `The Common class loader loads all classes and JAR files contained in $CATALINA_HOME/lib. These resources are visible to all applications and to Tomcat.` but usually it should work with `WEB-INF/lib` how do you build the WAR file?

Comment: I have tried adding jars in both the way..Its not working still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

By adding servlet-api.jar from apache tomcat library in to projects->properties->java build path, Solved the error.